# Unable to install Hadoop and Spark through Gremlin Shell

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, gremlin, tinkerpop

I am trying to install hadoop-gremlin and spark-gremlin through the Gremlin shell.

I downloaded [Gremlin console 3.2.0-incubating](https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/incubator/tinkerpop/3.2.0-incubating/apache-gremlin-console-3.2.0-incubating-bin.zip).

When I run `bin/gremlin.sh`, the gremlin console launches without error. However, I am unable to install spark-gremlin or hadoop-gremlin.

```
gremlin> :install org.apache.tinkerpop spark-gremlin 3.2.0-incubating
==>Error grabbing Grapes -- [unresolved dependency: com.github.jeremyh#jBCrypt;jbcrypt-0.4: not found]
gremlin> :install org.apache.tinkerpop hadoop-gremlin 3.2.0-incubating
==>Error grabbing Grapes -- [unresolved dependency: com.github.jeremyh#jBCrypt;jbcrypt-0.4: not found]
```

The following (seemingly relevant) jar exists: `$HOME/lib/apache-gremlin-console-3.2.0-incubating/lib/jBCrypt-jbcrypt-0.4.jar`. Additionally, I set these environment variables before running the console:

```
GREMLINHOME=$HOME/lib/apache-gremlin-console-3.2.0-incubating
export HADOOP_GREMLIN_LIBS=$GREMLINHOME/ext/spark-gremlin/plugin:$GREMLINHOME/ext/hadoop-gremlin/plugin:$GREMLINHOME/ext/gremlin-groovy/plugin:$GREMLINHOME/lib
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/client
export CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_HOME/*:$HADOOP_HOME/lib/*:$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop
```

While [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31031371/unable-to-install-gremlin-neo4j-through-gremlin-shell) appears very similar, it seems the solution is very specific to neo4j.

Please let me know if there is any other information I can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to set a Grapes configuration file under `~/.groovy/grapeConfig.xml`

```
<ivysettings>
  <settings defaultResolver="downloadGrapes"/>
  <resolvers>
    <chain name="downloadGrapes">
      <filesystem name="cachedGrapes">
        <ivy pattern="${user.home}/.groovy/grapes/[organisation]/[module]/ivy-[revision].xml"/>
        <artifact pattern="${user.home}/.groovy/grapes/[organisation]/[module]/[type]s/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"/>
      </filesystem>
      <ibiblio name="codehaus" root="http://repository.codehaus.org/" m2compatible="true"/>
      <ibiblio name="central" root="http://central.maven.org/maven2/" m2compatible="true"/>
      <ibiblio name="jitpack" root="https://jitpack.io" m2compatible="true"/>
      <ibiblio name="java.net2" root="http://download.java.net/maven/2/" m2compatible="true"/>
    </chain>
  </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

The `jBCrypt` dependency is coming from the `jitpack` repository.

You can read more about this in the [Apache TinkerPop documentation](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.2.0-incubating/reference/#gremlin-applications).

Comment: Thanks so much! I am now having an issue loading the hadoop plugin: (I get `No FileSystem for scheme: wasb` when I try). From research I've done, it sounds like this is a classpath issue, but it seems that my classpath is in order (spark-shell runs without an issue). Is this a simple fix or should I just ask this as a separate question?

Comment: sounds like a separate question